# Подписанные куки в NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Понятно когда сервер записывает куки: `res.cookie('monster', 'lalala');` и потом читает их `req.cookies.monster`.
Но для чего нужны подписанные cookie-файлы?
Которые записываются так: `res.cookie('monster', 'nom nom', { signed: true });`
и читаются `req.signedCookies.monster;`.
Как это влияет на защиту?

Answer (score 1):

Как очевидно из названия, куки могут быть подписаны, что являет собой защиту от подделки куков на стороне клиента.
Вычисляется HMAC подписанных кук и полученные значения проверяются при получении.
Если их HMAC не совпал - куки подделаны.
А что уже с этим делать - Ваше дело.

Comment: А в каком случае HMAC может не совпать? Если на клиенте произойдёт перезапись подписанных кук?

Comment: Да.............